# How to separate by special keyword in merged associative array without other library?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to find the array which has the specific keywords in merged associative array in SystemVerilog.

For example, I have the 4 arrays:

```
bit [31:0] arrayA[string];
bit [31:0] arrayB[string];
bit [31:0] arrayC[string];
bit [31:0] arrayD[string];

// Initialize the arrays
arrayA["key1"] = 100;
arrayA["key2"] = 200;
arrayB["door2"] = 300;
arrayB["door3"] = 400;

// Merge the arrays into arrayC
foreach (arrayA[key]) begin
  arrayC[key] = arrayA[key];
end

foreach (arrayB[key]) begin
  arrayC[key] = arrayB[key];
end
```

I have merged all into `arrayC[]`, and I want to find the array elements which have only the "*door*" string in the array keys.

But, SystemVerilog there is no `strtok()` method.

```
// Separate the merged array by keyword
foreach (arrayC[key]) begin
  string keyword;
  keyword = strtok(key, "door");  // strtok does not work.

  foreach (arrayC(key)) begin
     if (arrayC.exists(keyword)) 
        arrayD[key] = arrayC[key];
  end

end
```

I want to create a new `arrayD[]` from a merged `arrayC[]` with similar string keys that contain only the string I want, such as "*door*".

I want `arrayD` to have only these elements:

```
  arrayB["door2"] = 300;
  arrayB["door3"] = 400;
```

because `arrayD` was filtered to only have an array with the string "door".

How to find a special keyword in a merged associative array in SystemVerilog without a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr` to filter the keys for the ones which begin with the string "door".  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.16.8 *Substr()*.

```
module tb;

bit [31:0] arrayA[string];
bit [31:0] arrayB[string];
bit [31:0] arrayC[string];
bit [31:0] arrayD[string];

initial begin

// Initialize the arrays
arrayA["key1"]  = 100;
arrayA["key2"]  = 200;
arrayB["door2"] = 300;
arrayB["door3"] = 400;

// Merge the arrays into arrayC
foreach (arrayA[key]) begin
    arrayC[key] = arrayA[key];
end

foreach (arrayB[key]) begin
    arrayC[key] = arrayB[key];
end

// Separate the merged array by keyword
foreach (arrayC[key]) begin
    if (key.substr(0, 3) == "door") begin
        arrayD[key] = arrayC[key];
    end
end

$display("arrayD %p", arrayD);

end

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
arrayD '{"door2":300, "door3":400 }
```